# jQuery Mobile checkboxes controlgroup spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm having trouble setting up the jQuery Mobile checkbox Controlgroup. Below, you can see how checkboxes were expected to be and how it is currently in my application. Apparently, the internal spacing of my Controlgroup is larger than expected, and I have not changed any padding or margin property of the css.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh5t7fam/)

[image]

The HTML code of the page is:

```
<form>
    <fieldset class="ui-field-contain" data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="right">
        <legend>Swatch B:</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-t-2a" id="checkbox-t-2a" data-theme="a">
        <label for="checkbox-t-2a">One</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-t-2b" id="checkbox-t-2b" data-theme="a">
        <label for="checkbox-t-2b">Two</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-t-2c" id="checkbox-t-2c" data-theme="a">
        <label for="checkbox-t-2c">Three</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: JS Fiddle link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gh5t7fam/ @Varun

Comment: Have you copy pasted the code from somewhere? Because there are too many `&nbsp;` that came out of nowhere!

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm using Firefox, and in your fiddle, the checkboxes show up to the left of the labels, unlike your first screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the "Tidy" button in your Fiddle, it will adjust it.

To correctly align the button "Confirmar" just set an empty label, and remove the `ui-btn-inline` class (no need for extra inline styling here):

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <label for="btnConfirmar"></label>
  <a id="btnConfirmar" href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow  ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Confirmar</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The space between the checkbox is caused by copying the code from the JQueryMobile website.  If you view your elements using Chrome Dev Tools you'll see a bunch of spaces like this.  Just delete the spaces in your code between the tags.

Dev Tools screen shot from your fiddle:

[image]